# Regex pattern to split using either '==' or '='

Tags: java, regex, text, split, base64

The idea is to split base64 encoded string using '=' or '==' delimiter.

Source text might look like:

```
Zte+2RAEIEMU/2C6W6udzqkBKOM1Cp1R8tjbA17aAf0HZQ9NPpiJ7eWCA+r0Y00sRYFRwIMG/3IaOamst0WHNbB1QDZktNJxTIW4nYnA93Q=
Zte+2RAEIEMU/2C6W6udzqkBKOM1Cp1R8tjbA17aAf2yK8KmrbIGVD8vOyZj4uVg579ehXm9OrUsDebQ9C7OAg==
```

I have tried to use `(?<==)` for .split() method, but as you understand it leaves '=' empty string. In case of `(?<=\b[=])` - same issue, but second '=' in some cases removed.

The idea is to write something like "either use single '=' that has any character excluding '=' before and after, or use double '==' using same conditions. However, no success with this one.

Comment: try with `={1,2}`?

Comment: Please remember that base64 encoded string doesn't always end with = or ==. They are there only if the string needs to be padded for length. Why not using newline as delimitter? Your source text definitely looks like you could use it.

Comment: You could also use replaceAll: str.replaceAll("=", "").
EDIT: Fixed method, afaik replace only replaces first occurence of the string given.

Comment: try with =+  one or more = signs

Comment: @SimoErkinheimo You are totally correct - I have completely forgotten about newline as a delimiter. It has resolved my issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two Base64 encoded chunks of data, which are separated by a new line. You should split the string at the line break character. You can NOT rely on the existence of "=", since this is just for padding the last two bytes if neccessary. Sometimes there is one "=", sometimes there are two "==" and sometimes you will not find it at all.